# What does the CiviCRM Administration UI or civicrm_admin_ui actually do?

Tags: extension, admin, formbuilder

As the title says - what does this do? I know it says it replaces legacy pages with configurable search display forms - but what is considered legacy, what are these pages?

Also - personal annoyance - i hate seeing http://FIXME anywhere. These fields should be required for ui published extensions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it's just Custom Groups and Custom Fields. But I expect this extension to be short-lived as an extension - soon every page in civi will be a search kit. I'm joking a little bit but depending on who you talk to "legacy" means any page that isn't based on afform/search-kit.